# Nuxt: How can I prevent someone from leaving the page or refreshing? (If work not saved)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Can someone point me in the right direction for how to set this up?

Comment: You can't prevent actually, and you should not be trying to do so either. The best you can do is to show an alert and warn them that their data will get lost. And you can do it using Vanilla JS. You will find a lot of answers here at StackOverflow.

Comment: You are right. I just used plain JS and got everything working quickly. Thanks!

Comment: That's two jobs: figuring out [pending changes](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=dirty%20form) and [warning user](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event).